# DataGridView DataSource: Slow Assignment

Tags: c#, datagridview, backgroundworker

I have inherited a form and have been tasked with speeding it up.  Basically, it is a form which makes a `WCF` call to a service for some data, and then displays the data in a `DataGridView`.

I originally thought the bottleneck was the `WCF` call, so I moved that to a `BackgroundWorker`, to stop the UI from freezing up.

That helped a little bit, but it turns out that the bottleneck is actually this line:

```
DumpInfoGrid.DataSource = dumpGridBinding;
```

where the data retrieved from the `WCF` is assigned to the `DataSource` property.

---

The code basically boils down to this:

```
private BackgroundWorker dataGatherer;
dataGatherer.DoWork += dataGatherer_DoWork;
dataGatherer.RunWorkerCompleted += dataGatherer_RunWorkerCompleted;

private void dataGatherer_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    dumpGridBinding = WCF.GetDataFromService();
}

private void dataGatherer_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    DumpInfoGrid.DataSource = dumpGridBinding;
}
```

---

Is there anything I can do to speed this up?  Or any part I can move to the `BackgroundWorker` ?  The assignment freezes the UI for far too long.

Comment: Just wondering how big is this Data?

Comment: @Abhinav Its about 30kb for a days worth of data.  So 30kb * X, where X is the number of days the user wants to load.

Answer (score 2):

One possible solution for this would be to use FastDataGridView (or FastDataListView) which is found in [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/), which greatly improves the speed of the DataGridView control by not attempting to process all the records at one time.

Another solution would be to page the DataGridView you currently have, spreading out the load time across the pages as you use them [as seen here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19241/Paging-in-a-DatagridView)

Comment: In regards to your first paragraph, are you saying that the DataGridView attempts to process all the records at once?  Or that is what the FastDataGridView does?

Comment: Slight typo, fixed it in the original post now. DataGridView does that if Virtual mode is not enabled, as said below.

Answer (score 0):

You could use virtual mode - 
MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/15a31akc.aspx
This mode shows just the rows the user is looking at through the viewable region - you only load the rows actually being viewed - which is fast.

You handle the CellValueNeeded event and provide data from your list when the user scrolls through the list. Tex example shows you how to do that, but it's easy to write a linq statement to skip, take whatever is requested from your datasource (returned from the WCF service).